# What files or folders can I safely skip when uploading google-cloud library in Appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I just installed google-cloud-bigquery in my local GAE project (in a "lib" folder) following the instructions:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/tree/master/bigquery

This creates at least hundreds of files, including many I'm not sure would be useful on my live project (including a "Script (dev).tmpl" file in setuptools that aborts the upload process).

On assumption I've added all .exe files, and the setuptools folder to my app.yaml skip_files section, prior to my next uploading attempt. Please does anyone know more, or a proper list of files/folders I can skip from uploading, without hurting my live google cloud app?